# Redirect from admin page to user page by clicking a link button in gridview in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web site application which has admin and user page. Admin can view user information and also can visit their pages by cliking a link button . After cliking , it will pass user id in stored procdeure and it ll get usernamen and password and redriect the admin page to specific page in user site for example `Userweeklytimesheet.aspx with that username`

I just need an idea how to achieve this ..

Any help appreciate..

Comment: with that username or with the credentials of this particular user? The last is a bad, bad bad idea

Comment: As an administrator you don't have to retrieve the users' password to check their account, you just follow the role base membership techniques to give your site's admin a privilege to access users' account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is same as maintaining state between post backs
Here you can use Query String

like

> Response.Redirect("Userweeklytimesheet.aspx?UserName="+YourUserName);

[More find about QueryStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784(v=vs.90).aspx)